# Get all form controls in angularjs

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

What I would like to do is make all fields show their validation errors when:

- visiting and modifying a field so that its dirty state is triggered (the default), and also
- validating and triggering dirty when the submit is pressed

Take the following form

```
<div ng-form="MyForm">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="numbers" ng-required="'true'" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="numbers" />
    <span class="error" ng-show="numbers.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="numbers.$error.pattern">Pattern</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="text" name="characters" ng-required="'true'" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]*$/" ng-model="characters" />
    <span class="error" ng-show="characters.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="characters.$error.required">Pattern</span>
  </label>

  <button ng-click="validateAndSubmit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Essentially, I would like to create a directive that validates (sets dirty to true) for all the controls in an arbitrary form. Is there a simple way to get the form controls from the `FormController` without finding the actual dom elements?

Comment: Why not use the ngForm controller methods : `$setDirty()` and `$setValidity`? To use them, you should add a name attribute to your form and then call `$scope.formName.$setDirty()` More info: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController

Comment: Since they don't set the dirty state of the individual form controls

Comment: You can write a simple directive which can take custom validation methods and set dirty on the element accordingly. These custom validation methods can be defined on scope of controller and be accessible via isolate scope. This will make the same directive readily reusable.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but it seems like CSS (and possibly [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages)) would solve this. See **Using CSS classes** [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).